# Can I check if the selectedItem of comboBox is there in the itemsource or not using triggers and/or converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, triggers, converters

I have various comboboxes in various view which have different itemsource so I want a generic way to check if the user selected value is there in the corresponding itemsource. As the comboboxes are editable so I want to inform user when He is enetering a junk value like by changing Foreground to Red.

Comment: If the user is only allowed to choose his input from a given collection, why dont change your control to some kind of dropdown menu instead?

Comment: I have a editable combobox as the User has facility to directly type in the value He wants to select rather than selecting from drop down but I also wants to inform user when He is selecting a value which is not in itemsource.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="CustomComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox Name="cmbBox" Width="100" Height="30" IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" >
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is working but Foreground is not changing I checked this with ToolTip it shows message when user enters junks but it also shows message when the application starts. Don't know why its not working with Foreground.